# Need an efficient way to create one dataframe from a generator of json objects?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a generator:

```py
gen = ([{'Key': x, 'Data': {'value': i}} for i in range(3)] for x in ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I'd like to create one dataframe in the form:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Key': 'A', 'Data': 0},
    {'Key': 'A', 'Data': 1},
    {'Key': 'A', 'Data': 2},
    {'Key': 'B', 'Data': 0},
    {'Key': 'B', 'Data': 1},
    {'Key': 'B', 'Data': 2},
    {'Key': 'C', 'Data': 0},
    {'Key': 'C', 'Data': 1},
    {'Key': 'C', 'Data': 2},
])
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```py
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in gen:
    df = pd.DataFrame(x)
    df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: x['value'])
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df])

final_df.reset_index()
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with json. that is a list of dicts.

Comment: Can you replace the generator with one that directly gives you the "row" dicts you want? Or do you need to transform its output into proper rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `pd.io.json.json_normalize` and `from_iterable`

```
from itertools import chain

>>> df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(chain.from_iterable(gen))
```

---

```
  Key  Data.value
0   A           1
1   A           2
2   B           0
3   B           1
4   B           2
5   C           0
6   C           1
7   C           2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and then assign the column names.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([(key, data) for key in 'ABC' for data in range(3)], 
                 columns=['Key', 'Data'])
  Key  Data
0   A     0
1   A     1
2   A     2
3   B     0
4   B     1
5   B     2
6   C     0
7   C     1
8   C     2

# Or using a generator instead of a list comprehension:
pd.DataFrame(((key, data) for key in 'ABC' for data in range(3)], 
              columns=['Key', 'Data'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your generator `gen`, you can go through it and make a list of pairs (tuples). Then make your dataframe.

```
pairs = [(p['Key'], p['Data']['value']) for el in gen for p in el]
df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['Key', 'Data'])
```

Using your `gen`, `df` is:

```
  Key  Data
0   A     0
1   A     1
2   A     2
3   B     0
4   B     1
5   B     2
6   C     0
7   C     1
8   C     2
```

On my machine, this is roughly 3 times faster than your solution, at least with the "short" generator you have provided. This ratio may change with "longer" generators.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas 0.25 you can do `explode`

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(gen).explode().tolist()).assign(Data=lambda x : x['Data'].str.get('value'))
  Key  Data
0   A     0
1   A     1
2   A     2
3   B     0
4   B     1
5   B     2
6   C     0
7   C     1
8   C     2
```